# Issue with jquery code show and hide div

Tags: jquery

I have a small script that displays a checkbox, when checked it displays a select list. This works fine in jsfiddle but not when I use it on a web page.

The web page only contains the same code as the jsfiddle, no more no less.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".depository").hide();
$("#ImageSelection_0").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(".depository").show();
    } else {
        $(".depository").hide();
    }
});
</script>

Image depository: <input type="checkbox" name="ImageSelection" value="1" id="ImageSelection_0" />
Local image: <input type="checkbox" name="ImageSelection" value="2" id="ImageSelection_1" />


<div class="depository">
<select name="CompanyName" id="name" onChange="get();" class="imaindatesel">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>

    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>

</select>
</div>
```

the SJFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/mLvtmhrm/

Can anyone see why this don't work on my web page?

Many thanks for your input.

Comment: can you show us the actual website? (since that's where the problem is)

Comment: What happens in web page? Did you got any error in console? Wrap your code with `docuement.ready`.

Comment: If this is how it's ordered on your site, the problem is that `ImageSelection_0` doesn't *exist* yet when that script block runs. In the jsFiddle, the script doesn't run until later, at `onLoad` time. Move your script to a `$(document).ready()` handler, or at least to the end of the `body` tag.

Comment: Please paste the html also if there is an element exist with this id "#ImageSelection_0"

Comment: @VarunVasishtha There is HTML in the question already. It includes an element with that id.

Comment: @PaulRoub ah.. sorry my bad.. Click event is getting called or not may be you can use debugger; to check what is being done exactly

Comment: Also put all the scripts at last of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place all your jQuery code on document.ready event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".depository").hide();
    $("#ImageSelection_0").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $(".depository").show();
        } else {
            $(".depository").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

You have to do that, because your DOM does not exist when you try to attach event handlers or apply jQuery functions on them, while on jsfidle this works and I don't know the reason.

Comment: or put it at the end of page.

Comment: Right and the reason it's working in jsfiddle because the scriptlet you write in JavaScript section of jsfiddle will be embedded in window.load function that means DOM and other resources are loaded.

Comment: @Akki619 they might evaluate JavaScript only when DOM is ready so they could access user typed Javascript from their Javascript and this makes sense.

Comment: @Burimi no they use iFrame; the output section is an iframe.

Comment: @Burimi That was my stupid mistake. Many thanks for pointing this out. Perfect